# Combining Knockout with MVC4: Use a button to toggle columns in a table.

Tags: c#, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now I have the following code:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcAuction.Models.Furniture>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
</hgroup>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchIndex", "Furniture", FormMethod.Get))
{    
    <p>
        Description: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p> 
}
<table class="searchResults">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description) &nbsp
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndingDate) &nbsp
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category) &nbsp;
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price) &nbsp;
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
          <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndingDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                <button data-bind="click: toggleBidInput ">
                    <span data-bind="text: bidCancel"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind="visible: bidInputVisible" />
                <button data-bind="visible: bidInputVisible">
                    Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js")
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.bidInputVisible = ko.observable(false);
        self.bidCancel = ko.observable("Bid");
        self.toggleBidInput = function () {
            self.bidInputVisible(true);
            self.bidCancel("Cancel");
        };
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

</script>
}
```

So with this code I have a "Bid" at the end of each row of the table.
When I click on it, it gets renamed to "Cancel" and a Text Input and another "Submit" Button appear next to it (in all rows).

I would like to separate each "Bid" button so when I click on it only THAT button in that particular row changes to cancel and only in that row the Text Input and "Submit" Button appear.

I can't seem to separate the effects of the button for each separate row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KnockoutJS, by nature, is a "Client side library". I'm not sure if you can achieve what you expect by mixing the "client side code" with the "mvc4 server side code" like you mention.

Using KnockoutJS, when you bind a table's row (like for your example) to a list of items in a collection, the "click" commands become available to each items that it is bound to.

So, from what I can see in your example, I would do the following changes:

1) Put each Model.item in a collection within the ViewModel. ex: `self.items = ko.observable([])`

There are many ways to achieve this, but for the sake of this example, simply try this:

```
self.items = ko.observableArray([
   {
      itemDescription: 'desc 1', 
      itemEndingDate: '2012.01.01', 
      itemCategory: 'abc', 
      itemPrice : 123
   },
   {
      itemDescription: 'desc 2', 
      itemEndingDate: '2012.01.02', 
      itemCategory: 'bcd', 
      itemPrice : 234
   }
])
```

2) put the "toggleBidInput", "bidCancel" and "toggleBidInput" inside each items.

3) Bind the table's tbody to that collection. ex:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:items">..</tbody>
```

4) Bind the rows's cells to the proper items. ex:

```
  <tr>
    <td>
        <span data-bind="text:itemDescription"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span data-bind="text:itemEndingDate"></span>
    </td>...
```

When Knockout iterates through the items (the foreach..) the click button will be tied to the each item.

For point 1) (passing the data from the server to the client), there are many methods:

1) Use MVC's utility to generate JSON strings and put that string in a variable "model data".  use this "model data" to create the items that will include the extra observables and functions.

2) use ajax to "fetch" data asynchronously.  and populate the items from the values returned from the server.  Web API is great for this actually.  See John Papa's great article: http://www.johnpapa.net/2forfree/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Patrice! Seems like a good solution to my problem. Plus you give an answer to my main "concern" which was if it was possible to purely combine mvc model with knockout. Since i can't do that I will try your approach which I'm fairly confident will work. I will come back to accept your answer when it does.